# How do i include variables in url inside of Flutter

Tags: json, django, flutter

I want to put the value of email an password in the middle of the url insted of 1111 and 22222. The email and password values comes form text controllers and stored in email and password string. How can i put them in middle of url.
I tired ${email} insted of 1111
it gave error only static member can be initialized

```
String email = "";
String password = "";
String url ="http://2i6b753b.ngrok.io/authenticate/1111/22222";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use brackets. You can use like that but also works with brackets. You can try on https://dart.dev/#try-dart

```
main() {
  String email = "mail@example.com";
  String url = "http://2i6b753b.ngrok.io/$email/";

  print(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var url = Uri.parse("https://yourdomain.com/videos/$id");
```

you need to parse the url then you can add your id any extra variable .

then Call:

```
final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is insufficient as you do not provide any other information on the usage, but according to the `Only static members can be initialized` error, I will answer assuming that you are using this in a  `StatefulWidget` (not `StatelessWidget` because variables are not initialized with the keyword `final`).

Your code

```dart
String email = "";
String password = "";
String url ="http://ngrok.io/authenticate/$email/$password";
```

is the same as

```dart
String email = "";
String password = "";
String url ="http://ngrok.io/authenticate/${this.email}/${this.password}";
```

Here is the problem.
Variable `email` and `password` are members of the class, (technically of `this`). The variable `url` is also a member of the class and they are all initializers. Initializers are executed before the constructor of the class, and the constructor of the super class, and `this` is only allowed to be accessed after these constructions.
So, you can't use the value of the initializers during initialization. So, what can you do, you can use static members.

> Static members are data members (variables) or methods that belong to a static or a non static class itself, rather than to objects of the class.

According to Google, these static members are not the ones you want in your use case, as `email` and `password` members should be different for each instance of the class. So, the best fix I can advise is to use `url` as a function or a getter and not as a member, like

```dart
String get url => "http://ngrok.io/authenticate/$email/$password";
```

I hope it helps.