# Using BottomNavigation with State and build parameters

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So, i followed a few tutorials and created an app with bottom navigation:
[image]

First, I'm using authentication, so when the user open the app, it autenthicate the user and get the user information, and save it on the root Widget as a state, and then provides to the children widgets.

I was using a `switch` to make the page routes:

```dart
    switch (widget.destination.id) {
      case 'feed':
        return HomePage(widget.user);
      case 'account':
        return AccountPage(widget.user);
      default:
        return Text('404');
    }
```

But, the pages were building every time i changed the page on the bottom nav, so states between pages weren't saved. So i tried to create a list of pre-builded Widgets:

```dart
class LoggedInRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoggedInRoute(this.user);

  final User user;

  _LoggedInRouteState createState() => _LoggedInRouteState();
}

class _LoggedInRouteState extends State<LoggedInRoute> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
    // TODO: fix this
    HomePage(widget.user)
  ];
  // ...
}
```

But the Android Studio gives a error while doing this because of the user parameter:
[image]

How can i solve this? If it's helpful, the code is on my [github repository](https://github.com/musicorum-app/mobile-app/blob/master/lib/routes/logged_in.dart#L19-L22).

Comment: You have to do that assignment in initState() to be able to access widget.user
Also, I'd recommend using an IndexedStack with the bottom navigation bar. See this article: https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386

Comment: actually, i followed this article, but i found confusing because all the pages are the same, just changed icon, color and name, that is not my case, so i went with this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyLqj9L_Tck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same reason why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947733/7720975) happened.

You have to do,

```dart
class LoggedInRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoggedInRoute(this.user);

  final User user;

  _LoggedInRouteState createState() => _LoggedInRouteState();
}

class _LoggedInRouteState extends State<LoggedInRoute> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _pages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pages = <Widget>[
      HomePage(widget.user)
    ];
  }

  // ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thank you! But the page states are resetting when i change, i will try to rework everything because the structure is pretty bad

Comment: In case you want to freeze the state, you might want to try https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html out.